# .NET Core MVC localization set culture in library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm very frustrated, I try to work with the standard Microsoft localization mechanism.
But since two days now, I try to achive that I can set/change my current culture in an external library.

But it is ignored by the system. ;(

Here my StartUp.cs

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {                       
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>(); //TODO: With .net Core 2.1 services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

        services.AddPortableObjectLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Localization");              
        services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILocalizationFileLocationProvider, LocalizationLoader>());
    }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {   
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
            new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("de-DE"),            
            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });         

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.Routes.Add((IRouter) dynamicRouter);                     
        });
    }
```

And here is my controller action, which is in a library (Not the MVC application directly, may be important).
The action is called, no exception is thrown but the culture is always "de-DE" again in the IViewLocalizer.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string contentItemId)
    {
        // Just a try from the Internet
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(new CultureInfo("en-GB"))),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
        );

        // I thought one of these are right
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

        return View();
    }
```

Always if I reach the action again (F5 Browser refresh) CultureInfo is "de-DE" (Default) again. ;(

Comment: Why are you even using `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext` instead of just `this.HttpContext` (or even without `this`)? Also, what's `AddPortableObjectLocalization`? That's not the official way to do it

Comment: I had a similar problem and I solved it using a CustomControllerFactory, where I (in the `CreateController`function) set the _CurrentCulture_ and _CurrentUICulture_ and instantiate my library with the same culture.

Comment: You may find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984323/localization-in-asp-net-core/46984696#46984696) useful

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I don't use Controller in that "Controller" class, I just use the Controller Attribute. (For different reasons)
AddPortableObjectLocalization is official, it's just not resx files, it's .po files.
schlonzo: I will have a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your configuration in service like that :

```
 services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new[]
                {
                        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                        new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
                };

                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});
```

and after let the `UseRequestLocalization` empty :

```
 app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

Follow next link for complete startup :

https://github.com/AlexTeixeira/Askmethat-Aspnet-JsonLocalizer/blob/master/test/Askmethat.Aspnet.JsonLocalizer.TestSample/Startup.cs

Hope this help